# API call using Task.Result locking app

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have a piece of C# code (it's inside of a Xamarin app, but I don't think that's relevant) that initialises my app. It is like this:

```
class AppController {
    public override void InitializeApp() {
        // Do stuff to initialize services & database
        checkNeedsUpdates();
    }

    void checkNeedsUpdates() {
        Task.Run(() => {
            string json = API.Call("versions").Result
            // It never gets here
        });
    }
}

class API {
    HttpClient client;

    public Task<string> Call(string endpoint) {
        // Setup headers and access token things before handing over to POST function
        return Post(/*params*/);
    }

    public async Task<string> Post(/*params*/) {
        // Setup
        return await Request(/*params*/);
    }

    public async Task<string> Request(/*params*/) {
        HttpRequestMessage message = /*setup*/;
        HttpResponseMessage result = await client.SendAsync(message);
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Now the weird part is, I don't think anything has changed to this part of the app, I did add a little code to fix an issue with refreshtokens inside of the `Call` method.

Why does my app freeze? I know that using `Task.Result` inside an async method may cause a deadlock because it can't schedule itself or something, but I didn't change anything to or from `async` or `Task`

Comment: `.Result` *is* a blocking call so the question is a bit strange.

Comment: First of all, it makes a huge difference that the code is called from Xamarin (since it's a framework that has a Synchronization Context). Second, you should use `Task.Run(async () => { string json = await ... })`

Comment: `API.Call` returns Task so *don't* use `.Result` with it. use `await`. Use `async` in the lambda signature. If `checkNeedsUpdates` has to run in the background *save* the task somewhere so you can check eg for *failures*. Right now you don't know if you got an exception due to a connection error

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to run this operation on a threadpool thread? From what you've shown it may not be necessary. 'public override async void InitializeApp() { await checkNeedsUpdates(); }  async Task checkNeedsUpdates() { string json = await API.Call("versions"); }' may behave exactly as you want, all on the same thread.

Answer (score 5):

Ultimately, that `.Result` behaviour is undefined. Rather than worrying about what changed: just fix it...

```
Task.Run(async () => 
{
    string json = await API.Call("versions");
    //...
});
```

This is now well-defined and should work regardless of the sync-context status.

Comment: What do you mean by "behavior is undefined"?

Comment: @Evk there is no single specified thing that will happen; it *might* deadlock, it *might* work fine, causing a sync-wait - and which happens depends on something outside of your control (typically); but: you are not **meant** to touch `.Result` unless you know the task has already completed

Comment: Still interesting why it deadlocks, blocking on `Result` is inside `Task.Run` so should happen on thread pool thread where context cannot be captured. And also, isn't using `async void checkNeedsUpdates` and removing `Task.Run` at all a better fix in this situation?

Comment: @Evk `async void` is **almost never** a good idea; if you proposed changing it to `async Task CheckNeedsUpdates()` and removed `Task.Run()` : I'm all wth you

Comment: Well he calls it from InitializeApp which is parent class void method, and is technically an event, so I don't see why using Task is better than async void here (InitializeApp itself can be async void though).

Comment: @Evk yeah, in some ways I agree - and Task.Run doesn't make any guarantees about "when" etc; but I just can't bring myself to advocate `async void` :)